# Bind columns from two tables of a database into one gridview (Nonprogrammatically) ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql, visual-studio-2012, gridview, sqldatasource

There are several answers to this question across the internet but every one is programmatically, which is more complicated than necessary. There's a way to do it in visual studio with the built in functions and wizards.

I've done it before, you put the gridview on your webpage and click the smart tag. It's very easy to bind one single table to a gridview but I forget how to get a couple columns from one table and a couple columns from another table into a single gridview.

Comment: Create a view in sql and bind it to that?

Comment: There's an incredibly simple way on the tip of my tongue but I can't remember it. No coding, no writing SQL statements, you just use the smart tag of the GridView control.